# Cannot freeze field

Tags: python, django, django-south

Execute:

```
python ./mamage.py schemamigration --initial<br>
```

It gave me an error:

```
! Cannot freeze field 'exam.question.tags'
! (this field has class taggit_autocomplete_modified.managers.TaggableManagerAutocomplete)    
! South cannot introspect some fields; this is probably because they are custom
! fields. If they worked in 0.6 or below, this is because we have removed the
! models parser (it often broke things).
! To fix this, read http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/MyFieldsDontWork
```

Custom field class:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from taggit.forms import TagField
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

from widgets import TagAutocomplete        

class TaggableManagerAutocomplete(TaggableManager):
    def formfield(self, form_class=TagField, **kwargs):
        field = super(TaggableManagerAutocomplete, self).formfield(form_class, **kwargs)
        field.widget = TagAutocomplete()
        return field
```

My question is how to define `( "null": ["null", {{"ignore_if": "name"}],)` this line in model.py.

```
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
from taggit_autocomplete_modified.managers import TaggableManagerAutocomplete
    add_introspection_rules(
        [
            (
                (TaggableManagerAutocomplete, ),
                [],
                {
                    "null": ["null", {{"ignore_if": "name"}],
                },
            ),
        ],
        ["^taggit_autocomplete_modified\.managers\.TaggableManagerAutocomplete"])
```

If not define this line, I will get another error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'null'
```

[south.aeracode.org/ticket/422](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/422#)

Comment: ever fix this? got this issue exactly now (trying to override TaggableManager as well)

Answer (score 0):

https://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html
You can subclass _TaggableManager (note the underscore) to add methods or functionality. TaggableManager takes an optional manager keyword argument for your custom class, like this:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    # ... fields here
    tags = TaggableManager(manager=_CustomTaggableManager)
```